# Time Machine on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, time-machine

Is there a Time Machine like backup system for Ubuntu?  If not, what is the closest thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) to excellent effect. You can have it rsync and keep as many old versions, based on time as you want/have space for.  I've got 6 potential versions of things from today, daily for a week, 4 weeks, and then 6 months worth. I've already used it to recover several file I thought I'd lost due to overwriting.

The only problems I have had was it not running due to the previous run not completing in time, and so it left the lockfile dangling. This was on a remote machine that did password-less logins over SSH to rsync files off for backup/archive and I didn't log in very often to the server to check it. Running a logwatch script on there (emailing problems from the logs) at least made sure I saw the problems to restart it, and it's been hassle free ever since.  On my local server, it's been no problem at all.

Comment: Ah nice.  From that page: "Using rsync and hard links, it is possible to keep multiple, full backups instantly available. The disk space required is *just a little more than the space of one full backup, plus incrementals*."  You've used it for a while and found it stable then?

Answer (score 5):

You may want to try [Back In Time](http://backintime.le-web.org/)

Comment: You may want to point out that Back in Time is directly inspired by Time Machine, and uses `rsync` internally. http://lifehacker.com/5212899/back-in-time-does-full-linux-backups-in-one-click

Answer (score 5):

[Déjà Dup](http://live.gnome.org/DejaDup) (day-ja-doop) is a simple backup program. It hides the complexity of doing backups the *Right Way* (encrypted, off-site, and regular) and uses duplicity as the backend.

Features:

- Support for local or remote backup locations, including Amazon S3
- Securely encrypts and compresses your data
- Incrementally backs up, letting you restore from any particular backup
- Schedules regular backups
- Integrates well into your GNOME desktop

Comment: I've used this successfully for almost a year now, and backup has never been this painless.

Answer (score 4):

When using `rsync`, see [Time Machine for every Unix out there](http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/rsync_time_machine.html) for a tutorial, using the `--link-dest` option to create hard links to files that have not changed since the last backup. Like:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Mount point of the external disk
dest=/media/backupdisk

date=`date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"`
latest=$dest/latest
current=$dest/$date

rsync -aP --link-dest=$latest $HOME/Documents $current

ln -s $current $latest-$date
mv -f $latest-$date $latest
```

Mac OS X Time Machine not only uses hard links to unchanged files, but also uses hard links for folders in which no file has changed at all.

I *think* that most Unices do not allow hard links to folders, but if your `rsync` creates them, then beware when deleting old backups: you should use `unlink` to remove hard links to folders, and never remove any file you see in such hard-linked folder. When using `rm` on hard-linked *files*, only the hard link is removed. Good. But when recursing into a hard-linked *folder* and then deleting the files one sees there, the "original" files are removed and that affects all hard-linked folders that refer to the same thing, even more recent backups!

In other words: running something like `rm -R 20140101-221000` might recurse into hard-linked folders and then boldly invoke `rm` on the "original" files. You've been warned.

(The above site also mentions [FlyBack](http://flyback-project.org/), which still [gets comments](http://groups.google.com/group/flyback-discuss) though the latest [download](http://code.google.com/p/flyback/downloads/list) dates from <s>late 2007</s> May 2010. Maybe it's just very robust software, with no need for changes.)

Answer (score 2):

[TimeVault](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/TimeVault) was specifically designed to emulate TimeMachine.  The theoretical feature set is what *I* want from a TimeMachine clone, specifically the space savings.  Unfortunately it appears to be dormant: there's been little [development activity](https://launchpad.net/timevault) in a while.  I mention it for completeness, and because, if they can be prodded to work on it further, it looks quite promising.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of TimeBachine directly but we use [RSync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) with a scheduled [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job.

Comment: RSync is a good way to create a backup copy, but it doesn't help you keep a version history, which is, in my opinion, the handiest part of Time Machine.

Comment: @jtb, just to point out the obvious: Time Machine is mainly a backup system, not an archive (and certainly not a version control system). Especially files (or versions of files) that live shortly (less than a week) on your harddisk, may be expired from the backup much sooner than you may think.

Answer (score 0):

I for one am using Simple Backup Config/Restore, and backup the selected locations to an external hard-drive once every other day or so. Didn't have a problem as of yet, so I can't vouch for the restore part, but the backup one is OK.