# Script for CRON (FTP get files EVERY MINUTE)

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, cron, wget

I want to create a script that

- must run with a CRON every minute (Q: Is it wise to run CRON FTP/wget every minute?)
- compares local directory with remote directory (Q: do I use FTP or wget and how do I create
- obtains all the newer/changed XML files from the remote directory (Q: How do I throw that into one variable to use in loop later)
- mail notify the administrator as soon as this process fails
- copy newer/changed files_this_date to a directory_this_date

Is it possible or recommended to segment the scripts into config.sh, ftp.sh, copy.sh, mail.sh.
At the end I have to process the XML files with PHP

I know this is many questions (some parts has been solved) but for now I want to get an

- 1) opinion on viability/analysis
- 2) how to get $variable = (ls newer/changed files?)

Answer (score 2):

It would be a lot easier if you use rsync instead of wget as rsync has been designed exactly to give an answer to your need among other tasks. You could use:

```
rsync -raz -e ssh root@1.1.1.1:/root/dir-to-sync 
/root/dir-where-files-go
```

To check if the process fails simply check the exit code `$?` and if the value of this variable is distinct from zero "0" then something went wrong and you can flag an e-mail communication

To copy the changed files use a timestamp to know which is the last file you have before syncronizing and then you know which the new ones are.

You can create a date based mask in ISO format for your dirs with something like `newdirmask=$(date +%Y%m%d''%H%M%S)` and use it later to `mkdir` like `mkdir /home/$newdirmask`.

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for. Learning new and better ways to do this, but the remote is a client's Windows NT server with only a FTP Server. Can this be used to sync a working copy of my application between my localhost and development server?

Comment: Indeed, `rsync` is much easier, and will also work with remote Windows machines when mounting that as a local disk, @Wil. But rather than comparing timestamps, consider using `--link-dest`. (See [my answer here](http://superuser.com/questions/14730/timemachine-on-ubuntu/19610#19610).)

Answer (score 0):

You can install cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/) in your Windows server and have all the functionality of rsync in your Windows environment. Don't be afraid of the Cygwin website look&feel Cygwin is well known software and has been more than tested into production from my part.