# Hard Links in Windows - risk of file-loss?

Tags: sync, ntfs, storage, hardlink, backup

I am now creating hard links to remove duplicate space usage in backup data.
This is within single NTFS partitions.

I am afraid of data-loss - losing a file completely if one link reference is broken, other link references will be lost if one is deleted, or more versions change when one version change.

Is there some way to do this that will branch off the file if one changes.
(If there are two link references to a file, and one changes, we get 2 independent files.)

Any risks with syncing solutions like Dropbox?

For now I am only dealing with files, not directories.

Comment: Are you referring to changes on the backup disk directly, for *"If there are two hard links to a file, and one changes, we get 2 independent files"*? (Then: no, you cannot do that, and should always have multiple backup disks.)

Comment: Say I have 2 word documents that are the same, my duplicate cleaner could merge them so there are 2 links to the same file.  Though if I edit the file, only one should normally change (They should become two different versions, because the linking is just something I do to save space).

Comment: (Would be happy if someone could propose a better terminology).

Comment: How much data is really duplicated on your computer? I'd only use hard links on the backup, not on the source. That's also how Apple's Time Machine works, and [rsync's --link-dest option](http://superuser.com/questions/14730/timemachine-on-ubuntu/19610#19610).

Comment: ...and as for *"other versions (links to the same file) will be lost if one is deleted"*: no worries, that's not how hard links work. So, please read about how hard links work and come up with *a single* question? (And beware of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).) Now the only obvious answer is: yes, you can lose data, if you use hard links the wrong way.

Comment: @Arjan -1: So what is the wrong way?  How is this an XY problem?  (I am eplaining the actual problem).  How is this not a single problem?  (Mutable and immutable files are different, but from what I know there can be different ways to use had links and similar techniques).

Comment: @Arjan-2: These are backups of disks, cards etc.  Most of the volume is taken by big files like iso's, photos and videos.  Hard links let me have snapshots without using extra space.  As most files are immutable, regular  backups would not help much.

Comment: It sounded to me you were creating hard links on the source disk, to save space on the backup, which would have been an XY problem. Given your comments, now it sounds to me like you're using hard links on the backup disk for different backup dates (good, if you have multiple backup disks in case some space gets corrupted), but are doing that manually and/or are worried something would try to change files on the backup disk? Or is this related to some backup script you're using? And then there's also something about Dropbox, which again makes me think the hard links are on the source disk...?

Answer (score 0):

Branching off files in case of changes is easy using hard links: Just delete the file that changed by path and put the changed one in place. Hard links point to data, but are independent paths and therefore can be deleted without affecting other hard links or the data itself. The only risky part is writing directly into the file behind a hard link, because this of course would change the data for all hard links pointing to that data, simply because there's only one data for all "the same" hard links available. So you need to know if things have changed and if so need to create a new file.

As you are asking for backup purpose, your problem shouldn't arise anyway: Each change of a file should result in a new file in the backup, without any change you can create hard links to already available data. So your process would need to check for changes first anyway, I don't see where you need to decide if and how you want to change things in the backup. Backup is about leaving everything already present as it is and only decide how to add new things.

In general, I would not recommend implementing such things on your own, it's simply too complex and too easy to get things wrong. There are already solutions available implementing what you have in mind, e.g. a tool called [HardlinkBackup](http://www.lupinho.net/hardlinkbackup/).