# Is there a way to keep a backup of only the modified files in a directory (when being compared to another directory)?

Tags: linux, command-line, backup, rsync

***Note:*** I'm new to working with Linux but I've briefly researched the `rsync` *command and I'm pretty sure it's what I'll be using. Unfortunately, there's a lot of different options to this commands and I'm a bit confused on how to use it for my specific situation (outlined below).*

**Situation:** I have two directory's, one with a base set of files that have been downloaded from a repo (I don't want to modify these) and other with a working copy of the same repo. What I'm looking for is a command that compares my working copy of the repo to the static repo to see if there's any changed between the two. If there is a change, *only* the changed files will be moved to another directory (specifically for backups). The other constraint is that I want to keep the directory structure of the working copy (see example below).

**Example:**

***Static Repo:***

```
/src
    code1.java
    code2.java
/tests
    test1.java
```

***Working Repo:***

```
/src
    code1.java
    code2.java (modified)
/tests
    test1.java
    test2.java (added)
```

***Backups Directory:***

```
/src
    code2.java
/tests
    test2.java
```

Originally, the *Static Repo* and *Working Repo* would be the same and the *Backups Directory* would be empty. Once I make changes to the *Working Repo*, I could run the command I'm looking for and the *Backups Directory* would be populated appropriately (with only the new/modified files/directories).

**Does such a command exist?**

Comment: is there some reason you don't want to use `git`?  if your original is a git clone, your 'working' would be a local branch.  no extra directories or tools needed.

Comment: The team I just started working with is currently using SVN (which I'm also new too). Is git still an option in this case, without affecting any of the team's preexisting revision control setup?

Comment: ah.  well you could certainly git-ify your local copy of the svn repo, but that might be confusing if you're new to version control.  they take different approaches to some concepts.  probably better to get comfortable with svn first.  (note you should always be able to grab a fresh copy of the *"static repo"* from the svn server should you need one, but svn itself should be able to tell you exactly what changes you've made in *"working repo"*.)

Comment: Agreed with @quixotic about using source control, but I'd skip SVN and start using Git. It's 2017, you want to be able to work with github.com and the like. Even the Git tutorials are probably much more recent than SVN tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what problem you're trying to solve but I believe `git` probably could be a solution for it. But let's assume that the only acceptable option is some kind of backup script.

What I would use is `find` command to search for all files in **working_repo** newer than file in **static_repo** with latest modification time.

So I would start with [finding latest file in static repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015678/linux-most-recent-file-in-a-directory) and then use something like:

```
find <working_repo> -type f -newer <latest_file_in_static_repo> -exec rsync {} <backup_dir>/{} \;
```

options of `find`:

- `-newer <f>` Find files that were modified more recently than file `<f>`.
- `-exec <command>` execute `<command>` on each found file, where `{}` is replaced by currently processed file name.
- `-type f` Find only **f**iles (skip directories, symbolic links, sockets etc).

**Note**: I did not check command above, so it might have some errors or typos but in general it shows the idea.

Comment: Thanks, there is a slight issue with your suggested command but (as you said) it led me to figure out how to properly do what I wanted. What you suggested doesn't properly copy the entire directory structure of the modified files. I found a solution using `cp` here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83593/copy-specific-file-type-keeping-the-folder-structure

Answer (score 1):

A sane backup keeps history. And to able to read it on any system, I'd aim for something like:

```
20170125-230000
  /src
      code1.java (version 1)
      code2.java (version 1)
  /tests
      test1.java (version 1)

20170126-000000
  /src
      code1.java (version 1) hardlink to 20170125-230000
      code2.java (version 2)
  /tests
      test1.java (version 1) hardlink to 20170125-230000 
      test2.java (version 1)

20170126-010000
  /src
      code1.java (version 1) hardlink to 20170125-230000
      code2.java (version 2) hardlink to 20170126-000000
      code3.java (version 1)
  /tests
      test1.java (version 2)
      test3.java (version 1)
```

To preserve disk space, `rsync` can use `--link-dest` to create hard links for files (or maybe even folders) that have not changed. Of course, that also implies that if some sector on the backup disk goes bad, all history of some unchanged file might be lost (say `code1.java (version 1)` above, which effectively is only stored on disk once, while it is in all backup folders). So: always rotate the backup disks.

See [Time Machine on Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/14730/time-machine-on-ubuntu/19610#19610) for an implementation, and to read the warnings about understanding hard linked folders. But you probably want to use something like [rsnapshot](https://github.com/rsnapshot/rsnapshot).

(And indeed, the answer to your real problem is Git. But even then you need to make backups. Always create backups. Always.)