# Robocopy move old files instead of override

Tags: backup, robocopy, incremental-backup

I'm really new to robocopy and can't find if my idea can be realised.

I want to make a backup folder let's say destination "backup". But every time robocopy finds a file different from the backup I already have (newer, deleted, whatever) I want it to move the already existing file to a new destination like "old backup" (perfect would be if it could name the folder after current date).

Practical example:

Grandma crops a picture and overwrites the original.
Me doing backups every now and then.

MONTH later grandma is crying "where is the original?"

1. Usually the new (cropped) picture is flagged as newer and overrides the old one. Picture gone, grandma sad.
2. What I wish: Robocopy recognises the file has changed, moves old file to "old backup" and puts the new file in the main "backup" folder.
   Original Picture is in the "old backup" folder and grandma is happy.

PS: Any other program capable of doing that is also welcome:PS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these -

**1**. [freefilesync](https://freefilesync.org/)

> FreeFileSync is a folder comparison and synchronization software that
> creates and manages backup copies of all your important files. Instead
> of copying every file every time, FreeFileSync determines the
> differences between a source and a target folder and transfers only
> the minimum amount of data needed.

**2**. Windows File History
[image]
[image]

**3**. You can try creating a script
Hints/similar questions -

3a. [way-to-keep-a-backup-of-only-the-modified-files-in-a-directory](https://superuser.com/questions/1171190/is-there-a-way-to-keep-a-backup-of-only-the-modified-files-in-a-directory-when)

3b

> [how-to-backup-files-before-overwriting-them-with-rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53742197/how-to-backup-files-before-overwriting-them-with-rsync)
>
> --backup option of rsync
>
> ```
> -b, --backup
> With this option, preexisting destination files are renamed as
> each file is transferred or deleted. You can control where the
> backup file goes and what (if any) suffix gets appended using
> the --backup-dir and --suffix options
> ```

3c. [backing-up-specific-files-before-replacing-them-based-on-source-folder-contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288068/backing-up-specific-files-before-replacing-them-based-on-source-folder-contents)

3d. [use-rsync-for-backup-without-overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146703/use-rsync-for-backup-without-overwrite)

Comment: Free File Sync with customised versioning did a perfect job, thanks a lot.  https://freefilesync.org/manual.php?topic=versioning

Answer (score 1):

Syncthing and GsRichcopy360 are so far so good ,both have great features and solid for me so far in testing and using. Installation was painless, and  uses WAY less resources than CPU.
Both can do the required tasks in your question

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy can hardly keep different versions of changed files. What you need is more like an incremental backup strategy, which can auto back changed files at the scheduled time point.

There are many backup software can do this for free, you could refer to [incremental and differential backup](https://www.ubackup.com/features/incremental-differential-backup.html). And I think there's no problem to use robocopy at the same time.